# jekyll / css not working on github pages, but it works on localhost:3000

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I am new to Github and I’ve been trying to deploy my blog (forked from [kimfucious](https://github.com/kimfucious/sakura)) on Github pages. I have tried to deploy it by using surge and it worked. While when I upload it to Github, it says the CSS is not being applied.

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVxlJ.png)

[Here are the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb5iU.png)

I’m obviously doing something wrong. But I can’t figure it out.

Here is my repo: https://github.com/Colawithrain/Collin_Blog

And here is the Github pages link: https://colawithrain.github.io/Collin_Blog/

Thank you in advance for any pointers.

Colin

Answer (score 5):

It's a little confusing since it likely works locally (where you don't need a `baseurl`). It's one of the most common errors with Jekyll in combination with GitHub Pages. Here's the run down:

You are trying to load:

```
https://colawithrain.github.io/assets/css/main.css
```

However, the CSS file is being served at:

```
https://colawithrain.github.io/Collin_Blog/assets/css/main.css
```

You are currently requesting this in `_includes/head.html` with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css">
```

Fix this by changing it to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ site.baseurl }}/assets/css/main.css">
```

Then setting this in your `_config.yml`:

```
baseurl: /Collin_Blog
```

Comment: Although other pictures and elements still cannot be loaded, shall I just add {{ site.baseurl }} in front of every href addresses?

Comment: Yes, that will work. Jekyll offers some helper functions called `absolute_url` and `relative_url` that do something similar but I find `{{ site.baseurl }}` clearer.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Fixed it for me, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting `url` and `baseurl` in the config. Because it looks like the site expects it to be on the root domain and not at `/Collin_Blog`. For example, the CSS file is referenced at:

```
https://colawithrain.github.io/assets/css/main.css
```

But is actually at:

```
https://colawithrain.github.io/Collin_Blog/assets/css/main.css
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

I have tried to modify the url to https://colawithrain.github.io

And baseurl to /Collin_Blog

But it still doesn't work